# PHP/MYSQL/JSON: Parse complicated string or reassemble as dictionary

Tags: php, arrays, json, regex

I receive a complicate string through JSON that represents an object:

```
    <Offers: 0x170483070> (entity: Offers; id: 0xd00000000b880006 <x-
coredata://03C4A684-2218-489C-9EF6-42634ED10552/Offers/p738> ; data: {\\n    
topic = nil;\\n    topid = 9403;\\n    hasserverid = nil;\\n    isprivate = nil;\\n 
   lasttouched = \\\"2018-07-08 16:49:01 +0000\\\";\\n    lastviewed = nil;\\n
    localid = 42;\\n    needpicsync = nil;\\n    needsync = nil;\\n    secondorder
 = 0;\\n    oid = 0;\\n    offer = test;\\n    offerdone = nil;\\n    offernumber =
 70;\\n    userid = 1;\\n    wasdeleted = nil;\\n    whenadded = \\\"2018-07-08
 16:04:20 +0000\\\”;\\n})
```

I would like to save certain things to MYSQL.  In the above example, I would like to save the fields offer and offernumber among others to a record with something like:

```
$sql = "INSERT into offers (offer,offernumber) VALUES ('test',70)";
```

To do this, of course, I first have to parse the string to get the value for offer, the one for offer number and ideally, the keys and values for the entire object.

Should I first convert the string into some sort of array,dictionary or data structure?  Or should I try to parse the string using regex or some other method?  If the latter, would appreciate suggestions on what what regex or technique to use.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Have you made any attempts of solving this before asking? Also, where does that string come from? It looks crazy.

Comment: The string is an NSManagedObject from an iphone that is being synced.  it is one of an array of similar objects.  I can probably parse this in a hacky way by looking for the ;\\n between key value pairs but I was wondering if someone might have an elegant approach for doing it and/or  have some insight into whether it is better to first convert it into structured data before parsing it.

Comment: You should start by making some attempts. If you later want to know if there is a better way, you should post it in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). SO is for when you have specific issues with your existing code.

Comment: Magnus, if you think that a json object looks crazy, maybe this is not the best question for you weigh in on.

Comment: Just because I think that string look crazy (which it does), doesn't mean I can't help with the issue. My point was that you _always_ should make an attempt to solve the issue yourself before asking. This time, you were lucky getting an answer anyway, but you could just as easily have gotten more down votes and have the question closed for the lack of attempt.

Comment: I tried lots of things.  They would not have added value.  Fortunately, a talented programmer familiar with the subject provided exactly the insightful answer I sought.  Since this topic was not previously on SO, the answer will provide value to others for years to come and increases the value of the SO archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to convert the string into a object with PHP,
this may help you:

```
$input = "**The input string**";

// Remove the escaped new lines
$jsonString = str_replace("\\n", "\n", substr($input, strpos($input, "data: ")+5));
$jsonString = substr($jsonString, 0, strlen($jsonString) - 1);

// Convert the equals, semicolons and remove the escaped backslash
$jsonString = str_replace(";", ",", $jsonString);
$jsonString = str_replace("=", ":", $jsonString);
$jsonString = str_replace('\\', '', $jsonString);

$matches = array();

// Use regex to get json key-value
if(preg_match_all('/(\w+)\s*\:\s*(.+)\s*\,/m', $jsonString, $matches,PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)){
    // Iterate the matches and enclose key and value into double quotes
    foreach($matches as $item){
     // Enclose the value if isn't a number or a date
        if(strpos(trim($item[2]), '"') !== 0 && !is_numeric($item[2])){
            $item[2] = '"'.$item[2].'"';
        }
        // Replace in json string
        $jsonString = str_replace($item[0], '"'.$item[1].'"'.' : '.$item[2].',', $jsonString);
    }
}

// Remove last comma
$jsonString = substr($jsonString, 0, strlen($jsonString) - 3) . '}';

// Transform json string to object
$jsonObject = json_decode($jsonString);

// Show the json string
echo($jsonString);

// Display the object
var_dump($jsonObject);
```

the above code convert the given string to an object and then you can use the properties as you need.

you can try this here: [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d07c951f37d2911025ebb6d963d54e31cfac5268)

Comment: Awesome.  Thank-you.  The PHP Sandbox is also new to me so thanks for that as well.

Comment: One follow up?  How would I get the value for offer?  jsonObject['offer'] is returning null

Comment: Hi there, the properties should be reached with ->, so, for offer should be $jsonObject->offer.